# Prove, for every nonnegative integer $n$, that $5^{2n} + 2^{2n} ≡ 2^{2n+1}\pmod{21}$.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, induction

Is my proof correct? Thanks in advance.

**Base step: n = 0**
$$5^{2 \times 0} + 2^{2 \times 0} ≡ 2^{2 \times 0+1} \pmod{21}$$
$$= 1 + 1 ≡ 2 \pmod{21} \checkmark$$
**Inductive hypothesis: assume $5^{2n} + 2^{2n} ≡ 2^{2n+1} \pmod{21}$ is true when $n=k$**:
$$ 5^{2k} + 2^{2k} ≡ 2^{2k+1} \pmod{21}$$
Since the statement above is true we can write the following:
$$5^{2k} + 2^{2k} - 2^{2k+1} = 21x$$
Simplify and rewrite:
$$2^{2k} = 5^{2k}-21x$$
**Now we proceed with the inductive step: $n = k + 1$**:
$$5^{2(k+1)} + 2^{2(k+1)} ≡ 2^{2(k+1)+1} \pmod{21}$$
$$5^{2k+2} + 2^{2k+2} ≡ 2^{2k+3} \pmod{21}$$
Rephrase the statement above:

$$21 \mid (5^{2k+2} + 2^{2k+2} - 2^{2k+3})$$

$$21 \mid (5^{2k+2} - 4 \times 2^{2k})$$
Replace $2^{2k}$ with $5^{2k}-21x$:
$$21 \mid (5^{2k+2} - 4 \times (5^{2k}-21x))$$
Multiply out:
$$21 \mid (5^{2k+2} - 4\times 5^{2k} + 4\times 21x))$$
$$ = 21 \mid (25 \times 5^{2k} - 4\times 5^{2k} + 4\times 21x))$$
$$ = 21 \mid (21 \times 5^{2k} + 4\times 21x))$$
$$ = 21 \mid 21(5^{2k} + 4x))\checkmark$$
Hence
$$5^{2(k+1)} + 2^{2(k+1)} ≡ 2^{2(k+1)+1}  \pmod{21}$$
$\blacksquare$

Comment: Alt. hint (without induction): $\;5^{2n}+2^{2n}-2^{2n+1}=5^{2n}-2^{2n}=\dots\,$

Comment: @dxiv sorry, I don't understand how I can use that in my proof.

Comment: Your proof looks ok, but it is needlessly complex.  Life gets much simpler if you just look $\pmod 3$ and $\pmod 7$.

Comment: @aa Remember the difference of powers identity, and use it for $\,5^{2n}-2^{2n}=25^n-4^n\,$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof you gave is correct.

However, it can actually be done with a lot less work and without induction:
$$5^{2n}=\left(5^2\right)^n=25^n\equiv 4^n=2^{2n} (\mathrm{mod}\ 21)$$
Hence $5^{2n}+2^{2n}\equiv 2\cdot 2^{2n}=2^{2n+1} (\mathrm{mod}\ 21)$.

Comment: At least try to verify the correctness of OP’s answer. The question wasn’t “solve this problem.” Being more complex does not mean it is wrong, and the exercise might be part of learning about writing induction proofs.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I've checked the proof now and edited my answer accordingly.